# Adding all Person objects into combobox

Tags: java, foreach, jcombobox

Hello I have the following code

```
RekeningApp app;
Persoon persoon;
JComboBox personenList;

PersoonView(RekeningApp app) {

    this.app = app;

    personenList = new JComboBox();

    personenList.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());


}
```

Now I need a Foreach loop that goes through an arraylist filled with Persoon objects that is in the RekeninApp class.

For this arraylist I have a getter in RekeningApp like this

```
List<Persoon> Pers = new ArrayList<Persoon>();

 public List getPersonen() {

    return Pers;

}
```

So right after I make the combobox there must be a foreach loop only the problem is that when I make a loop It says the types are incompatible.

```
for (Persoon p : app.getPersonen()) {
        personenList.addItem(p);    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a typed `List` to avoid casting.

```
public List<Persoon> getPersonen() {
    return Pers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I make a loop It says the types are incompatible.

That is because you are using a raw type `List` as return type. Iterating over such `List` will get you an `Object` and not `Persoon`. Change the return type to `List<Person>`:

```
public List<Persoon> getPersonen() {
    return Pers;
}
```

---

**Related Post:**

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1679863)